# Executing the java program from command prompt

Tags: java

I have a java program in a Folder(template).There is a sub directory(lib) which has all the libraries.
How do i execute the java program from the command prompt?

I need to do the above stuff using process builder. How should i do that in the case of process builder too

Comment: Take a look at the following java tutorials.  They are very quick to go through and would answer your question thus preventing the downvotes.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html   If after looking at those you still don't get it, you need to post more detailed information.  LIke the name of the file, the path, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Set classpath of `lib` before exceute the program.

i.e.

`set classpath='c:\lib\jarname1.jar;c:\lib\jarname2.jar'`

Answer (score 1):

To compile:

`javac yourJavaFile.java`

To run with classpath:

`java -classpath .;youLibrary yourJavaFile`

Classpath Explained:

The `;` separates files. So for example if you wanted to add three files you could write this `-classpath .;file1;file2;file3`.

It is sometimes easier to create a small batch or bash script (depending on your OS) which has these commands in it. That way you're not writing it more than once. Here is an example of a Windows batch script. Name this file `foo.cmd` and to run it open the command line, type `foo.cmd` and hit enter.

```
@echo off

rem Set LIB_HOME to the place where your Lib folder is located
set LIB_HOME=C:\Temp\Template\Lib

java.exe -cp "%LIB_HOME%\file1.jar;%LIB_HOME%\file2.jar;%CLASSPATH%"   a.package.name.to.your.file.Main
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) is some documentation on setting the classpath and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html) is some documentation on running a program from a MS Windows command line.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, to compile - it's just

```
javac MyClass.java
```

then to run:

```
java MyClass
```

But make-sure that you have your Classpath set correctly >

So you can do :

Set classpath of lib before exceute the program.

i.e.

set classpath=My_CLASS_PATH

[See  Setting the class path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: Java program is dependent on the libraries which are there in lib folder

Comment: lets say if i have 20 libraries inside lib folder. Do i need to set all the 20 libraries to the classpath

Comment: @user2074252- yes, you would ,

Comment: How do i execute the above stuff using process builder

Comment: what is process builder ?

Comment: ProcessBuilder is a library. By using ProcessBuilder we can execute the java program like we execute it from command prompt

Answer (score 0):

1] Well, first thing to do is to write a code that you want to run and save that as a Java executable file. For this purpose you can use either MS word or Notepad.

2] then you should make sure of proper indentations since neither notepad nor wordpad would help you with that and also that the file is saved as a "**.java**" file and not as a "**txt**" file. you can read more on this here -->

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-prompt

3] Now open command prompt and run its administrator.

4] Next up, use the java command (java compile) to compile your program.